# How does Mac OS X handle file permissions?

Tags: macos, security, file-permissions

I'm actually quite surprised that this isn't a quickly googlable question. I was doing some research on file systems and their implementations in this [book by tanenbaum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136006639). It lists a number of ways that Unix based systems implement their file/resource security mechanisms.

I have a basic understanding of domains, groups, user ids and protected resources as well as Access Control Lists. I also understand that there are various ways of managing these ACLs such as [protection Matrixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_Matrix) (one axis is domains, one is files), [file based permissions](http://www.softpanorama.org/Access_control/acl.shtml) (where each file has a list of owners/groups/domains that may read/write/execute a file) and its reciprical owner ACLs (where each owner has a list of Files and RWX permissions).

My main question is what approach doe Mac OS X take in managing these file permissions or more specifically, Their ACL's? what happens when I change these file permissions with `chmod` for a file? A Technical answer would be much appreciated and I won't accept an answer straight away to allow for someone to give a detailed answer.

**UPDATE:** I Have come across [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57848/file-permission-mechanism-in-unix-like-systems) as a guide to the meaning of the octet bits in a file permision mod (using `chmod`) but it does not allude to the underlying storage of this ACL.

Comment: is this a programming question or a general MacOS / Finder type question?

Comment: My intention is to understand unix/osx file permissions to allow my java programs to succesfully read, write and execute files on osx. I thought it a good question to add. currently my `ProcessBuilder` throws a `can't execute binary files` message when it tries to call `cat myfile.txt` and I have a feeling it has to do with my file permissions.

Comment: [This](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/introduction-to-os-x-access-control-lists-acls/1048/) may be a good intro.